# After updating my rails version I couldnt execute my project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im getting this error while executing after updating rails version, What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNvMQ.png)

Comment: Hello - we need to see some evidence of research and the things you have already attempted to do to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what version you are trying to upgrade from and what your current version is.

`rake rails:update`

[Here is how to upgrade from 3.2 to rails 4.0](http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/06/upgrading-to-rails-4-0-from-rails-3-2-test-case-part-i-preparations-configuration-gems/)